# Sphorium WebDAV Server Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webdav

Does anyone knows how to working with Sphorium WebDAV Server Framework?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sample application on the source-forge site, that implements DAV server that is using file system as the repository.

You can use this sample application as the starting point.

Basically you need to create your implementation of WebDAVModule, which is an IHttpModule and add logic for authentication/authorization and processing of requests.

Furthermore you'd need to implement the HTTP methods you're interesting in (depends are you going to create Class 1 or Class 2 server). Each method has it's own base Sphoirum class that has support for delegate based processing of the DAV pipeline.

Again, you can look into the sample application for the reference implementation for all HTTP methods for Class 1 and Class 2 servers.

Comment: Do you recall where the sample application is? I'm not seeing it when referencing the link above. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Source code is at https://sourceforge.net/p/webdav/code/HEAD/tree/, but code does not completely implement all methods and there are some bugs which should be fixed.